# Cut and take new line String with maxchar

Tags: c#, .net, string, winforms

I tried to create a function for print all the articles of a billing with some max length vars, but when this max length is exceeded Index out of range errors appears or in another cases total and quantity Doesn't appear in line:

Max Length variables:

```
private Int32 MaxCharPage = 36;
private Int32 MaxCharArticleName = 15;
private Int32 MaxCharArticleQuantity = 4;
private Int32 MaxCharArticleSellPrice = 6;
private Int32 MaxCharArticleTotal = 8;
private Int32 MaxCharArticleLineSpace = 1;
```

This is my current function:

```
private IEnumerable<String> ArticleLine(Double Quantity, String Name, Double SellPrice, Double Total)
{

    String QuantityChunk = (String)(Quantity).ToString("#,##0.00");
    String PriceChunk = (String)(SellPrice).ToString("#,##0.00");
    String TotalChunk = (String)(Total).ToString("#,##0.00");

    // full chunks with "size" length
    for (int i = 0; i < Name.Length / this.MaxCharArticleName; ++i)
    {
        String Chunk = String.Empty;
        if (i == 0)
        {
            Chunk = QuantityChunk + new String((Char)32, (MaxCharArticleQuantity + MaxCharArticleLineSpace - QuantityChunk.Length)) +
                    Name.Substring(i * this.MaxCharArticleName, this.MaxCharArticleName) +
                    new String((Char)32, (MaxCharArticleLineSpace)) +
                    new String((Char)32, (MaxCharArticleSellPrice - PriceChunk.Length)) +
                    PriceChunk +
                    new String((Char)32, (MaxCharArticleLineSpace)) +
                    new String((Char)32, (MaxCharArticleTotal - TotalChunk.Length)) +
                    TotalChunk;
         }
         else
         {
             Chunk = new String((Char)32, (MaxCharArticleQuantity + MaxCharArticleLineSpace)) +
                    Name.Substring(i * this.MaxCharArticleName, this.MaxCharArticleName);
         }
         yield return Chunk;
     }

     if (Name.Length % this.MaxCharArticleName > 0)
     {
         String chunk = Name.Substring(Name.Length / this.MaxCharArticleName * this.MaxCharArticleName);
         yield return new String((Char)32, (MaxCharArticleQuantity + MaxCharArticleLineSpace)) + chunk;
     }
}

    private void AddArticle(Double Quantity, String Name, Double SellPrice, Double Total)
{
        Lines.AddRange(ArticleLine(Quantity, Name, SellPrice, Total).ToList());
}
```

For example:

```
    private List<String> Lines = new List<String>();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddArticle(2.50, "EGGS", 0.50, 1.25); // Problem: Dont show the numbers like (Quantity, Sellprice, Total)
        //AddArticle(100.52, "HAND SOAP /w EP", 5.00, 502.60); //OutOfRangeException
        AddArticle(105.6, "LONG NAME ARTICLE DESCRIPTION", 500.03, 100.00);
        //AddArticle(100, "LONG NAME ARTICLE DESCRIPTION2", 1500.03, 150003.00); // OutOfRangeException
        foreach (String line in Lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
```

Console Output:

```
LINE1:     EGGS
LINE2:105.6LONG NAME ARTIC 500.03   100.00
LINE3:     LE DESCRIPTION
```

Desired output:

```
LINE:2.50 EGGS              0.50     1.25
LINE:100. HAND SOAP /w EP   5.00   502.60
LINE:  52
LINE:105. LONG NAME ARTIC 500.03   100.00
LINE:  60 LE DESCRIPTION
LINE:100. LONG NAME ARTIC 1,500. 150,003.
LINE:  00 LE DESCRIPTION2     03       00
```

Comment: This is a lot of code, and you have not shown what values are passed in that are creating an issue.  Suggest you simplify the code you are posting to a minimal example that demonstrates the issue, including specifying what parameters you are calling the method with.

Comment: `(String)(Quantity).ToString("#,##0.00");` is redundant.  `Quantity.ToString("#,##0.00");` will accomplish the same thing.  Also `Lines` is already a list, so calling `.ToList()` here `Lines.AddRange(ArticleLine(Quantity, Name, SellPrice, Total).ToList();` is redundant as well.

Comment: Good tip, I will keep it in mind. :)

Comment: Can you post an example of the raw input?  It looks like you may be overthinking the solution (plus you're generating an awful lot of strings, so if you have a lot of text to process you may see performance issues).  I suggest using `StringBuilder` unless you need to control the length of the strings at such a granular level.

Comment: @JonathanEdgardo Exactly Tim was right. Use StringBuilder to append the string for new line use Environment.NewLine .

Comment: Hy thank you for your comments, i need save each line in a `List<String>` because i will use a loop for print in `e.Drawings`. `StringBuilder` only will returns a single item into `List` that is the because i use `yield return`, the `ArticleLine` problem is the numbers split you can see the sample output and the desired output. So if you have another efficient method to do that please tell me always saving multi lines.

Comment: It's not clear why you're checking the length of the Name variable, but if you look at your `for` loop, for the first article line, the value of `i` will be 1 (due to the `++i` operator), which means the `else` block is executed.  If you want to limit the length of the values in the string, simply use `Substring` on it, like this:  `string name = Name.Substring(0, MaxCharArticleName);`.  You can `Trim()` the results if you don't want blank spaces.

Comment: Yes i agree but remember i need to print all the `Name` variable without lose any character what is why i need a new line, same with `Quantity, Sellprice` and `Total`.

Comment: I use chars limit because is a roll paper size. And limitations are many.

Comment: Ok.  I think I've figured out what you're trying to do.  You want to split the input across multiple lines if any of the values exceed the predefined max length.   In this case, checking the length of `Name` alone isn't going to suffice.  I'll try and post a more elegant solution later today if I get time.

Comment: Totally correct, I appreciate the intent of helping @Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to take values (string values, ultimately) and extract specified lengths from them (chunks), where the each individual chunk of a given group goes on one line, and the next chunk(s) go on the next line(s).  There are several challenges in your posted code.  One of the biggest is that you may not understand what the `/` operator does.  It is, of course, used for division, but it is *integer* division, meaning you get a whole number as the result.  E.g. 3 / 15 gives you 0, whereas 17 / 15 would give you 1.  This means your loop *never* runs unless the length of the value is greater than the specified chunk limit.

Another possible issue is that you only perform this check against `Name`, not the other items (though you may have omitted the code for them for brevity reasons).

Your current code is also creating a *lot* of unnecessary strings, which will lead to performance degradation.  Remember that in C# strings are *immutable* - meaning they cannot be changed.  When you "change" the value of a string, you are actually creating *another* copy of the string.

The crux of your requirement is how to "chunk" the values in such a way that the correct output is achieved.  One way to do this is to create an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) that will take a string value and "chunkify" it for you.  One such example is found here: [Split String Into Array of Chunks](http://lukencode.com/2010/04/21/split-string-into-array-of-chunks/).  I've modified it slightly to use a `List<T>`, but an array would work just as well.

```
public static List<string> SplitIntoChunks(this string toSplit, int chunkSize)
{

    int stringLength = toSplit.Length;

    int chunksRequired = (int)Math.Ceiling(decimal)stringLength / (decimal)chunkSize);
    List<string> chunks = new List<string>();

    int lengthRemaining = stringLength;

    for (int i = 0; i < chunksRequired; i++)
    {

        int lengthToUse = Math.Min(lengthRemaining, chunkSize);
        int startIndex = chunkSize * i;
        chunks.Add(toSplit.Substring(startIndex, lengthToUse));

        lengthRemaining = lenghtRemaining - lengthToUse;
    }

    return chunks;
}
```

Say you have a `string` named `myString`.  You would use the above method like this:  `string[] chunks = myString.SplitIntoChunks(15);`, and you would receive an array of 15 character strings (depending on the size of the string).

A quick walk-through of the code (as there is not much explanation on the page).  The size of the chunk is passed into the extension method.  The length of the string is recorded, and the number of chunks for that string is determined using the `Math.Ceiling` function.

Then a `for` loop is constructed with the number of chunks required as the limit.  Inside the loop, the length of the chunk is determined (using the lower of either the chunk size or the remaining length of the string), the starting index is calculated based on the chunk size and the loop index, and then the chunk is extracted via `Substring`.  Finally remaining length is calculated, and once the loop ends the chunks are returned.

One way to use this [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) in your code would look like this.  The extension method will need to be in a separate, `static` class (I suggest building a library that has a class dedicated solely to extension methods, as they come in quite handy).  Note that I haven't had time to test this, and it's a bit kludgy for my tastes, but it should at least get you going in the right direction.

```
private IEnumerable<string> ArticleLine(double quantity, string name, double sellPrice, double total)
{

    List<string> quantityChunks = quantity.ToString("#,##0.00").SplitIntoChunks(maxCharArticleQuantity);
    List<string> nameChunks = name.SplitIntoChunks(maxCharArticleName);
    List<string> sellPriceChunks = sellPrice.ToString("#,##0.00").SplitIntoChunks(maxCharArticleSellPrice);
    List<string> totalChunks = total.ToString("#,##0.00").SplitIntoChunks(maxCharArticleTotal);

    int maxLines = (new List<int>() { quantityChunks.Count, 
                                      nameChunks.Count,
                                      sellPriceChunks.Count,
                                      totalChunks.Count }).Max();

    for (int i = 0; i < maxLines; i++)
    {

        lines.Add(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}",
                                quantityChunks.Count > i ?
                                quantityChunks[i].PadLeft(maxCharArticleQuantity) :
                                String.Empty.PadLeft(maxCharArticleQuantity),
                                nameChunks.Count > i ?
                                nameChunks[i].PadLeft(maxCharArticleName) :
                                String.Empty.PadLeft(maxCharArticleName, ' '),
                                sellPriceChunks.Count > i ?
                                sellPriceChunks[i].PadLeft(maxCharArticleSellPrice) :
                                String.Empty.PadeLeft(maxCharArticleSellPrice),
                                totalChunks.Count > i ?
                                totalChunks[i].PadLeft(maxCharArticleTotal) :
                                String.Empty.PadLeft(maxCharArticleTotal));                                    
    }

    return lines;     
}
```

The above code does a couple of things.  First, it calls `SplitIntoChunks` on each of the four variables.

Next, it uses the `Max()` extension method (you'll need to add a reference to `System.Linq` if you don't already have one, plus a `using` directive). to determine the maximum number of lines needed (based on the highest count of the four lists).

Finally, it uses a 4`for` loop to build the lines.  Note that I use the ternary operator (`?:`) to build each line.  The reason I went this route is so that the lines would be properly formatted, even if one or more of the 4 values didn't have something for that line.  In other words:

```
quantityChunks.Count > i
```

If the count of items in `quantityChunks` is greater than `i`, then there is an entry for that item for that line.

```
quanityChunks[i].PadLeft(maxCharArticleQuantity, ' ')
```

If the condition evaluates to true, we use the corresponding entry (and pad it with spaces to keep alignment).

```
String.Empty.PadLeft(maxCharArticleQuantity, ' ')
```

If the condition is false, we simply put in spaces for the maximum number of characters for that position in the line.

Then you can print the output like this:

```
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

The portions of the code where I check for the maximum number of lines and the use of a ternary operator in the `String.Format` feel very kludgy to me, but I don't have time to finesse it into something more respectable.  I hope this at least points you in the right direction.

**EDIT**

Fixed the `PadLeft` syntax and removed the character specified, as space is used by default.

Comment: Deeply I appreciate your help, thanks to you I found the ultimate solution. Thanks